# AWS Stepfunctions: Use a JSON value as part of JSONPath?

Tags: json, aws-step-functions

I have a JSON document which looks like this

```
[
  {
    "ChallengeData": {
        "Answer": "d00b2151c0ee4b4cc688e0377940981a"
    },
    "ChallengeHash": "e3acc830b1de2b06a4040654ba6a2e4a"
  },
  {
    "CurrentHashes": {
      "d00b2151c0ee4b4cc688e0377940981a": 0,
      "673b352ffb77d08ea9953cc24907b5b3": 1,
      "c8fd8f2484063948c1cc7ec48ea2db0f": 2,
      "9d73f4c8620cf0e17b4c98e3272e2bff": 3
    }
  }
]
```

This is the Input for my latest Pass state before the answer is going to be send to the client. The answer should be the numeric value from the `CurrentHashes` section. To look this up, previous states have calculated that the key here is the one being present in `$.[0].ChallengeData.Answer`.
So I would like to use `$.[0].ChallengeData.Answer` to get the value from `$.[1].CurrentHashes`.
How can this be achived?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit on how exactly your question is related to Step Functions? Are you trying to implement an input path filter or what? Thank you.

Comment: @Quassnoi done :)
If it's still unclear let me know.